# Sharepoint2010 Log File

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, logs

Iam trying to generate sharepoint 2010 log file by command line Merge-SPLogFile.

But when i launch management shell it  shows

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not regis tered.

I tried Merge-SPLogFile

> PS C:\Users\Administrator> Merge-SPLogFile -Path F:\SPLogs
>   Merge-SPLogFile : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version
>   4.0.30319.34209 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime. At line:1 char:1
>   + Merge-SPLogFile -Path F:\SPLogs
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...letMergeLogFile:    SPCmdletMergeLogFile)
>   [Merge-SPLogFile], PlatformNotSupportedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMergeLog    File
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator> Merge-SPLogFile
>
> cmdlet Merge-SPLogFile at command pipeline position 1 Supply values
>   for the following parameters: Path: F:\SPLogs Merge-SPLogFile :
>   Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version
>   4.0.30319.34209 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime. At line:1 char:1
>   + Merge-SPLogFile
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...letMergeLogFile:    SPCmdletMergeLogFile)
>   [Merge-SPLogFile], PlatformNotSupportedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMergeLog    File
>
> PS C:\Users\Administrator>

Do i need to update .Net Runtime on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `-Version 2` to your SharePoint Management Shell command line in the shortcut. This will force PowerShell to use .NET 2.0.

[SharePoint 2010 Management Shell does not load with Windows PowerShell 3.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2796733)

Comment: Does this work ? Merge-SPLogFile -Path F:\SPLogs -Version 2

Comment: No, read the article I linked. You need to modify your shortcut.

Comment: Its working after changing root from properties.
i do have enough permisions on folder but it still says "PS C:\Users\Administrator> Merge-SPLogFile -Path F:\SPLogs
Merge-SPLogFile : Access to the path 'F:\SPLogs' is denied.
At line:1 char:16
+ Merge-SPLogFile <<<<  -Path F:\SPLogs
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...letMergeLogFile:
   SPCmdletMergeLogFile) [Merge-SPLogFile], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMergeLog
   File

PS C:\Users\Administrator>"

Comment: Make sure you're running the SharePoint Management Shell as Administrator. Make sure you actually do have access to F:\SPLogs by navigating there with Windows Explorer on the local machine.

Comment: Tried that too but no luck :/

Comment: Oh, your cmdlet is wrong. `Merge-SPLogFile -Path F:\SPLogs\mylogfile.log`.

Comment: Its working :) Thanx for Bearing with me im totally new to SP